# Arduino to C# Data Receive

Tags: c#, arduino

I've asked this question earlier today, but have refined my code so am putting a new question up here.

This is the code I have at the moment:

**Arduino Code:**

```
void setup()
{
 pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(13,LOW);

 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
 if(Serial.available() > 0)
 {
  char letter = Serial.read();

  if (letter == 'A')
  {
   digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
   Serial.println("THE LED IS ON");
  }
  else if (letter == 'B')
  {
   digitalWriter(13,LOW);
   Serial.println("THE LED IS OFF");
  }
 }
}
```

I have a C# program with an onButton, offButton, and textboxInterface. This is the code I have in C#.

**C# Code:**

```
using System.IO.Ports;

public partial class Form1: Form
{
 public static System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serialPort1;
 private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string line);

 public Form1()
 {
    InitizlizeComponent();
    System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(components);
    serialPort1.PortName = "COM7";
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
    serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
    serialPort1.Open();
    serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
 }

 private static void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataEventReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    textboxInterface.Text = indata;
 }
```

I think that is mostly right (?), the only error I am getting is as the last *textboxInterface* with an error coming up saying: *An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Arduino_Interface.Form1.textboxInterface'*

Can someone please show me what stupid thing I'm doing...

Comment: Don't delete your question and then post the same thing.  You have an edit button.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I thought there were enough changes in my code to merrit it. Won't do in the future.

Comment: something wrong with your textboxInterface.
try create a new dummy winform project, and create the textbox, simulate the code to access its Text property, without any of those serialport stuffs, compare it with your code, it's like your textbox is not properly construted (you handcode it? or copy-n-paste?)

Answer (score 0):

First, remove `static` from the declaration of `serialPort1_DataReceived`. You need access to the form's instance fields so it cannot be `static`.

Second, this event will be raised on a background thread and you cannot update the UI from that thread. You will need to marshal the call to UI thread to update the textbox. Something like this:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataEventReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textboxInterface.Text = indata));
}
```